# ggplot2 plotmatrix with free scales

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I use plotmatrix to find correlations in a data frame:

```
# Reduce dataset to 1000 to make things run faster
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000),]
plotmatrix(d[,-c(2:4)]) + geom_smooth(color="steelblue", method="lm")
```

This works fine, as long as the different columns are of the same scale.  If they are not, the columns with a small scale become useless. As you can see if you run the example above, price is the largest, and so it kills all the other columns.

To solve this problem in a grid, I would usually ask ggplot draw each scale independently using:

```
scales="free_x"
```

However, how can I pass that into plotmatrix, or make plotmatrix scale Independently somehow?

[image]

Comment: Note that `?plotmatrix` still describes itself as "experimental". Try switching to `ggpairs` in the **GGally** package. It's design/defaults are rather different, but it handles the free scales for you by default, I believe.

Comment: ggpairs looks pretty nice.  It definitely solves the scale problem.  However, it's not as easy to combine with other elements, e.g. geom_smooth.

Comment: I agree that there is not (yet) a truly great option for this kind of plot. Have you tried `ggpairs(d[,-c(2:4)],
  lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))`, though?

Comment: That's pretty good.  I'll post that answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from joran above, using ggpairs from the GGally package:

```
# Reduce dataset to 1000 to make things run faster
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000),]
ggpairs(d[,-c(2:4)], lower=list(continuous = "smooth"))
```